# Usage of object attribute in swing paint methods

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to create a maze using swing.

For now, I just want to create a 10x10 grid using lines, which would be all around my cells (a 40x40 square, from the "w"). I'm trying to create each lines of my square depending of my  `boolean[] walls` tab ( `walls[0]` is top,  `walls[1]` is right,  `walls[2]` is bottom and  `walls[3]` is left).
If the value is  `true`, then we have a wall, if not, the passage is opened and no line on this side.
I'm using an  `ArrayList<Cell>` for collecting the differents cells of my grid.

All of this is working (it seems) but I've came across a problem.
Indeed I would like to use my object's (Cell) attributes in  `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for doing custom dimensions of cells.
But, I don't know really how to do this. I've tried to separate my  `Cell class` and do another class for my graphic interface but it didn't worked out as well.

```
public class Cell {
    int i,j;
    int w = 40;
    ArrayList<Cell> grid = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    boolean[] walls = new boolean[4];
    boolean visited;


    public Cell () {
        this.setup();
    }


    public Cell(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;

        this.walls[0] = true;
        this.walls[1] = true;
        this.walls[2] = true;
        this.walls[3] = true;

        this.visited = false;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }

    public void setup() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);

        int cols = (int) f.getWidth()/w;
        int rows = (int) f.getHeight()/w;

        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell(i,j);
                grid.add(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 

        int x = i*w;
        int y = j*w;

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        if (this.walls[0])
            g.drawLine(x    , y    , x + w, y    );

        if (this.walls[1])
            g.drawLine(x + w, y    , x + w, y + w);

        if (this.walls[2])
            g.drawLine(x + w, y + w, x    , y + w);

        if (this.walls[3])
            g.drawLine(x    , y + w, x    , y    );
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cell();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call a method?

Comment: No, you can't call the paintComponent methods. I'm asking how I could use my attributes "i" and "j" in my paintComponent in order to create a visual grid.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"..but it didn't worked out as well."* What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? You'll need to be a **lot** more specific if we are to have much chance of helping.

Comment: *"No, you can't call the paintComponent methods."* While that is true of the methods in a `JComponent`, that method is also defined in this class which is **not** a `JComponent`. I would advise renaming it to something less confusing like `draw(Graphics)` and calling that method on each instance of the `Cell` from the custom painted `JPanel`.

Comment: The more I look at that code, the crazier it gets.. `public class Cell {
    ..
    ArrayList<Cell> grid = new ArrayList<Cell>();` - why does the `Cell` class contain a list of `Cell` objects (which would each contain a list of `Cell` objects, which would.. keep going forever)?

Comment: I edited my post the best I could. Sorry if I'm not the clearest. I'm actually learning with the links given in the answer for custom painting. @AndrewThompson , I'm using an  `ArrayList<Cell> ` for keeping my cells in order to create my maze later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a paintComponent(...) method to a class and expect that method to be invoked.

To do custom painting you override the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel`. So you need a custom panel. The panel would contain the `ArrayList` of `Cell` objects and in the `paintComponent()` method you iterate through each Cell object and paint it.

So first you need to start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to learn the basics of painting a single object.

Once you understand that you can check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which shows how to paint from a List of objects.